# Determine current month to open file based on path and name that changes monthly

Tags: excel, vba, path

I am writing in Microsoft 2010 OS and Excel 365. I have written a script to process a 150K row file.

It opens a source file located in a SharePoint drive:

"\(server name)\SQL Files\2022\06.2022\June2022Name.xlsx"

There are files for each month over the past year and a new folder is created as the months progress.
In June, there is no folder for July but it will be written as
2022\07.2022\July2022Name.xlsx

I would like to open the file that matches the current month.

This is what I tried so far

```vb
'Find Workbook Filename <br>
Dim dt as String, dt2 as string
Filename as String, strMonth as string<br>

strMth = Monthname(Month(Now()), True<br>
if Month(Now()) = 1 Then<br>
   strPriorMth = MonthName(12,True)<br>
Else st PriorMth = Monthname(Month(Now())-1, True<br>
dt2 = StrMonth(mm).YYYY
dt = StrMonth(mmm)YYYY
<br>
filename = "\\(server name)\SQL Files\2022\"dt2"\"dt & "SqlViews.xlsx"<br>
```

I'm unsure how to cast the dt2 as a number string and dt as what I think is a nvarchar string.

Comment: Is `StrMonth()` supposed to be a function?

Comment: I lifted that from another answered question on StackOverflow. It looked like it was a way to generate the current month. should I not use it the way I have it included?

Comment: Yea, don't lift code you don't understand. That's how you get ransomware. So my guess is that it's a function. You will need the code for that as well.

Comment: how would you accomplish the task with VBA script?

Comment: Function is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the exact output you want. But here is an example.

```
Sub test()

Dim dt As String, dt2 As String
Dim filename As String, strMonth As String

strMth = MonthName(Month(Now()))
If Month(Now()) = 1 Then
    mth = "12"
    strPriorMth = MonthName(12, True)
Else
    mth = Month(Now() - 1)
    strPriorMth = MonthName(Month(Now()) - 1, True)
End If

dt = Format(mth, "mm")
dt2 = Format(mth, "mmm")

filename = "\\(server name)\SQL Files\2022\" & dt2 & "\" & dt & "SqlViews.xlsx"

Debug.Print filename

End Sub
```